# Spring AOP continues iteration after throwing

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have `MyClass` and `AopLogger`. The iteration stops if `doSomething` has an exception.

How to prevent exiting in `logAround` and continue with the next host? And what is the `Object` returned by `logAround` good for, what can we do with this `Object`?

```
class MyClass{
    void check() throws Exception {    
        Iterator<Host> iter_host = configReader.getHostMap().values().iterator();       
        while (iter_host.hasNext()) {               
            Host host = (Host) iter_host.next();
            host.doSomething();
        }
    }
    void doSomething(){} //Exception 
}

class AopLogger {    
    @Around("execution(* com.mypackage..*.*(..))")
    Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable{ 
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();   
    } 
}
```

Comment: you don't give enough information; if the join point is at doSomething method (assuming it is public), then it should be enough to put try catch block around return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(). "What it is good for.." you may log when you enter into doSomething, and when the method returns; actually it is strange that this is missing in your code.

Comment: when i put the try catch block around return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed() the iteration ends and application exits. When i put the try catch block around host.doSomething() the iteration continues, but i can't log anything in the logAround

Comment: first find out what is the joinpoint: put a breakpoint in your IDE on return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed() and inspect the various fields of ProceedingJoinPoint - you should see which method is intercepted. Try to reason from there.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your aspect class should have an `@Aspect` annotation. Secondly, if you want to use Spring AOP and not full AspectJ your aspect and all target classes should also be Spring `@Component`s.

Having said that, here is a little sample. I created it with plain AspectJ, but the aspect code should be the same in Spring AOP.

**Helper classes to make the code compile and run:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Random;

public class Host {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private String name;

    public Host(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if (RANDOM.nextBoolean())
            throw new RuntimeException("oops!");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Host(name=" + name + ")";
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ConfigReader {
    private Map<Integer, Host> hostMap = new HashMap<>();

    public ConfigReader() {
        hostMap.put(1, new Host("mercury"));
        hostMap.put(2, new Host("venus"));
        hostMap.put(3, new Host("earth"));
        hostMap.put(4, new Host("mars"));
    }

    public Map<Integer, Host> getHostMap() {
        return hostMap;
    }
}
```

**Driver application:**

I did not like the `Iterator` which is a relic from older JDK versions, so I replaced it by more modern Java style `for` loop.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

class MyClass {
    private ConfigReader configReader = new ConfigReader();

    void check() throws Exception {
        for (Host host : configReader.getHostMap().values()) {
            System.out.println(host);
            host.doSomething();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MyClass().check();
    }
}
```

**Aspect with pointcut/advice doing logging and exception handling at the same time:**

Please also note my comment at the very end of the code.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class AopLogger {
    private static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> indent = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String initialValue() {
            return "";
        }
    };

    @Around("execution(* de.scrum_master.app..*(..)) && !execution(* toString())")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        System.out.println(indent.get() + ">> " + thisJoinPoint);
        try {
            indent.set(indent.get() + "  ");
            result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
            indent.set(indent.get().substring(2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(indent.get() + "Caught exception: " + e);
            indent.set(indent.get().substring(2));
        }
        System.out.println(indent.get() + "<< " + thisJoinPoint);

        // Attention: If a method with a caught exception does not have 'void'
        // return type, we return a (probably unexpected) result of 'null' here.
        // So maybe we should not catch all execptions but rather pick more
        // specific joinpoints where we are sure we can cleanly handle the
        // corresponding exceptions.
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
>> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.main(String[]))
  >> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.check())
    >> execution(Map de.scrum_master.app.ConfigReader.getHostMap())
    << execution(Map de.scrum_master.app.ConfigReader.getHostMap())
Host(name=mercury)
    >> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
      Caught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: oops!
    << execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
Host(name=venus)
    >> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
    << execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
Host(name=earth)
    >> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
      Caught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: oops!
    << execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
Host(name=mars)
    >> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
      Caught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: oops!
    << execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())
  << execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.check())
<< execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.main(String[]))
```

**Second aspect variant separating logging from exception handling:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class AopLogger {
    private static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> indent = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String initialValue() {
            return "";
        }
    };

    @Around("execution(* de.scrum_master.app..*(..)) && !execution(* toString())")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(indent.get() + ">> " + thisJoinPoint);
        try {
            indent.set(indent.get() + "  ");
            Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
            indent.set(indent.get().substring(2));
            System.out.println(indent.get() + "<< " + thisJoinPoint);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            indent.set(indent.get().substring(2));
            System.out.println(indent.get() + "<< " + thisJoinPoint);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Around("execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Host.doSomething())")
    public void handleException(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(indent.get() + "Caught exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

The log output stays the same, but this time the exception handling is in a separate advice with a more precise pointcut. The logging advice only takes care of logging (it would not even need try-catch if it was not for the correct indentation). The exception handling advice does only its own job.

Feel free to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks, i think the problem is with the Apache BasicDataSource. The method dosomething creates a jdbc pool. The method check() ends if the host is not reachable. When i put the check() in try catch block it work. I'm trying another way now doing the same in a runnable class but don't know how to implement void run() method that it can throw Exceptions. I mean void run() throws Exception